# Android.media.audiofx.Visualizer: некорректная работа на некоторых девайсах

Tags: android, java

Привет всем! Капчу весь выходящий аудио поток из андроида при помощи `android.media.audiofx.Visualizer`

При этом на одном телефоне работает всё хорошо, а на другом (при проигрывании собственным плеером написанном на С), аудиопоток не капчится (проигрывается всё исправно), а вот

```
onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] fft, int samplingRate)
```

всё время возвращает массив `fft [] = {0,0,0....0,0}` - 1024 нуля, вне зависимости от того что играет или не играет.

Если кто-то знает возможную причину некорректной работы напишите пожалуйста.
Телефон на котором НЕ работает новый с новым андроидом 4.2, на 2.3 4.1 и 4 всё работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве гипотезы:

В API 16 появились несколько новых констант и методов капчения аудио контента, в частности:

> public static final int SCALING_MODE_AS_PLAYED
> Added in API level 16 Defines a capture mode where
> the playback volume will affect
> (scale) the range of the captured
> data. A low playback volume will lead
> to low sample and fft values, and
> vice-versa.

По русски это означает, что если громкость установлена в "ноль", то самплинг будет никакой. Копайте вокруг этого... Возможно просто на аппаратах с API 16 качество капчения по умолчанию нулевое и надо рученьками прописывать `public int setScalingMode (int mode)`, чтобы код был универсальный имеет смысл организовать вызов этой функции через рефлексию (поскольку метод доступен только для API 16)

Comment: Какбы там же нормально всё капчится если проигрывать при помощи встроенного андроидного плеера.
Почему-то другой плеер, который самописный, никак не капчится.

Спасибо богльшое, потестю и отпишусь, пока не буду закрывать вопрос.