# Можно ли дебажить встроенные классы Android

Tags: android

Привет всем, у меня всё ещё есть вопрос: [Android.media.audiofx.Visualizer: некорректная работа на некоторых девайсах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/211158/java-android-media-audiofx-visualizer-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85).

Но из этого вопроса вытекает более интересный: можно ли дебажить встроенные классы андроида?

Comment: сорцы подключи и дебаж

Comment: @Gorets Ну-ну попробуй подебажить исходники String.java :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы дебажить нужно, чтобы в объектном коде были ссылки на номер строки в исходнике, без номеров строки будет мягко говоря затруднительно. А из продакшна обычно изымают номера строк и отладочную информацию.

Если в библиотеках вы укажете ссылку на предварительно выкачанные исходники классов Андроида - то вы увидите какую конкретно процедуру вызывает ваш код, но дальше уже тьма...

Можно конечно заняться реверс инжинирингом объектников с их сборкой с дебаг информацией, но это занятие еще то. Тем паче если в коде будут вызовы нативных функций то рискует вовсе превратиться в реальный кошмар.